# How to calculate Percentage of total DISTINCT values

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to calculate percent of count of DISTINCT values? E.g. I have a dataset with people who can pick multiple symptoms (i.e each person can have 0 to 10 values).

```
person 1 - symptom A
person 1 - symptom B
person 2 - symptom B
person 2 - symptom C
person 2 - symptom D
person 3 - no symptoms
person 4 - symptom A
```

etc. E.g. if total UNIQUE count of people is 4 and 2 of them have picked symptom A, then I'd like to see: A = 2/4 = 50%, not A=2/6 = 33% (not what I need).

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . assuming symptoms are not repeated for a single person, then one method is:

```
select symptom,
       count(*) * 1.0 / (select count(distinct person) from t) as ratio
from t
group by symptom
```